# how can i write a sql query that finds rows where one column is a substring of another column

Tags: sql, t-sql

I wish to find all rows in a table where one column is a substring of another column.

In other words, suppose I have a table (called people) with two columns: firstname and lastname, and I want to find all people like "rob robinowitz" and "jill bajillion".

Is there a way to do something like "select * from people where lastname like %firstname%"?  (But something which actually works).

Comment: Out of curiosity, is that your real use case? Why do you want to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were close

```
select * from people where lastname like '%' + firstname + '%'
```

Alternative way (may be even faster)

```
select * from people where charindex(firstname,lastname)>0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySQL you could

```
SELECT * FROM people WHERE INSTR(lastname, firstname) <> 0
```